# REST API with Java, Tomcat, EclipseLink and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, rest, tomcat, jpa

i want to build a REST API with Java.
I have a MySQL Database and want to use EclipseLink as my JPA Provider.
I want to run it on a Tomcat Server, alternatively i will use another Server if needed.

Now my real question. How do i set all of this up in Eclipse using Maven?

thanks.

Comment: SO not really for starting points. It's for specific questions with specific answers.

Comment: Go to the [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) site and read up on their canned version of Tomcat, Jersey et al. It's the easiest way to get started.